# Having some issues with regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a line in one of my scripts that goes like this:

```
A=load '/bla/bla/bla/06/01/*/*/*'
```

Now 06/01 here refers to June 01. I want to include July 1 in this line as well using regex.

I know that you can do this using regex and will look something along the lines of:

```
(06/01)|(07/01)
```

But when I put this into my line:

```
A = load '/bla/bla/bla/(06/01)|(07/01)/*/*/*'
```

my script seems to be failing. This is probably because the interpreter assumes that 06 (from the first line above) is being replaced by `(06/01)|(07/01)`.

How do I go about using regex so that I can write code that essentially means this:

```
A=load '/bla/bla/bla/June 01 and July 01/*/*/*'
```

Will appreciate some help!

Edit 1: This is for pig scripts

Comment: You need to identify the host language for the regexes, and maybe some of what's in the bla's.  What you've got is not shell, for example.  And a lot may depend on what this `load` command is; it is possible that it is interpreting the regular expressions.

Comment: try to replace "(06/01)|(07/01)" with "(06/01|07/01)"

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - that should work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler your solution works! Thanks! But if I want to include something like June 01 and July 20 as well, how do I go about doing that. That is what I need to do and am struggling to do

Comment: Then we need information about which sub-species of regex is supported, and you probably go with one of the versions with alternatives properly parenthesized.  So, for 06/01 and 07/20, you'd need `(06/01|07/20)`, maybe with the non-capturing sigils: `(?:06/01|07/20)`.  But that depends on the sub-species of regex you have available to you (the 'sigil' is for PCRE — Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions, for example).

Answer (score 1):

If `(06/01)|(07/01)` is part of the regex, the alternation must be isolated from the surrounding expression.

Use `(?:06/01|07/01)` instead.

Comment: I'd just like to add that alternation has the *lowest* precedence of all the regex operators.

Comment: @fferen - There is no precedence, nor regex operators in the language itself. Alternations are served left to right.

Comment: This doesnt work for me :/
This is a pig script that basically that tries to load files that are in the directory of : '/home/files/2012/06/01/*/*/*'
So now, I wanted to include June 01 and July 1 or like June 01 and July 21. 
So I want something like this: '/home/files/2012/June 01 and July 21 /*/*/*'

Comment: @sln: perhaps precedence wasn't the right word. Binding? I mean it alternates between as much as it can get, instead of operating on one object at a time, like `+` or `*`. But this is probably not the place for it anyway. :X